# dojo 1.10 custom build

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I am trying to create a custom dojo build, using dojo sdk 1.10

I have the following directory structure -

```
   app
    build.profile.js
    dojo
    dijit
    dojox
    util
    myapp
     A.js
     B.js
     package.json
     myapp.profile.js
```

**both A.js and B.js are pure AMD modules. B is a dependency to A**.

here is my myapp.profile.js -

```
var profile = (function(){
return {
    resourceTags: {
        amd : function(filename, mid) {
            if(filename.indexOf('profile.js') != -1  && /\.js$/.test(filename))
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
};
})();
```

here is my myapp package.json -

```
{ 
"name": "custom",
"description": "My Application.",
"version": "1.0",
"keywords": ["JavaScript", "Dojo", "Toolkit", "DojoX"],
"dojoBuild": "myapp.profile.js"
}
```

here is my applicatio wide build.profile.js -

```
    var profile = (function(){
return {
    basePath: ".",
    releaseDir: "./build",
    releaseName: "javascript",
    action: "release",
    stripConsole: "warn",
    selectorEngine: "lite",

    packages:[{
        name: "dojo",
        location: "dojo"
    },{
        name: "dijit",
        location: "dijit"
    },{
        name: "dojox",
        location: "dojox"
    },{
        name: "custom",
        location: "myapp"
    }],

    layers: {
        "dojo/dojo": {
            include: [ "dojo/dojo", "dojo/i18n", "dojo/domReady"],
            customBase: true,
            boot: true
        },
        "custom/custom": {
            include: ["myapp/A"]
        }
    }
};
})();
```

All configurations look okay, but when i build i get the following error : -

```
error(311) Missing dependency. module: myapp/A; dependency: myapp/B
```

here is my A.js :-

```
define([
"dojox/mobile/Badge",
"dijit/_Widget",
"myapp/B",
], function(declare, Button, Bb){
    return declare("A", Button, {

});
});
```

here is my B.js :-

```
define([
"dojox/mobile/Badge",
"dijit/_Widget"
], function(declare, Button){
    return declare("B", Button, {

});
});
```

is there something that I am missing in my profile objects? I am blocked here and not able to build my project.

Comment: Try changing `"myapp/B"` in A.js to `"./B"` or `"custom/B"`

Comment: Wow, that worked for me , thank you buddy.

Comment: Both versions do work or only first one?

Comment: ./B worked, :) thanks again.

Please write that in the answer section so that I can mark it as solved and you get repo :)

Answer (score 0):

In the packages section you have like this

```
{
    name: "custom",
    location: "myapp"
}],
```

Whereas, while loading the module you are using `"myapp/A"` instead of `"custom/A"`. Try changing that and let me know if it works.

Comment: You need to do it in all the places where you are trying to access your modules. That means for `myapp/B` needs to be `custom/B`.

Comment: thanks bro, the comment in my question solved my issue, you are right, i did some mistakes in 'layers'